# Populate PHP Array from While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, while-loop

If I am fetching data from a MySQL database and using a while loop to iterate through the data how would I add each one to array?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Departments`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Build an array up as you iterate with the `while` loop.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Departments`");
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $results[] = $row;
}
```

Alternatively, if you used [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), you could [do this automatically](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: how to put only one column in an array and index od array should be the primary key?

Comment: @bhawin learn how PHP arrays work and you will find it simple

Answer (score 7):

This will do the trick:

```
$rows = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Departments`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This has been one of the fastest ways for me to create (multi-dimensional) arrays. I'm not sure if you want all of your results smooshed into one array or not.

```
// Read records
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Departments`"; 
$query = mysql_query($query);

// Put them in array
for($i = 0; $array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $i++) ;

// Delete last empty one
array_pop($array);
```

You can use print_r($array) to see the results.

Answer (score 2):

my fav is the following;

```
$result=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if ($result) {
    while($found_results[] = odbc_fetch_array($result)) { } 
    array_pop($found_results); //pop off the empty line from while loading
}
```

you dont need to pop the last line, but it does leave a blank if you omit it.
works the same for mysql obviously.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple columns in your Departments table and you want to save in different array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Departments`");
$dept_id = array();
$dept_name=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
//fetches and store all results in id column on your departments table
$dept_id= $row['id'];
//fetches and store all results in name column on your departments table    
$dept_name=$row['name'];
}
```