# Put sql into a variable

Tags: php

There are two rows given in mysql_query and I want each row put in a variables $date1 and $date2. My sample code is below.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $date1 = $row['TheDate'];
  $date2 = $row['TheDate'];
}
echo $date1;
echo $date2;
```

Comment: what is the problem? show your current output and your desired ouptut. One thing here at least is that you put the same information in both vars, and overwrite them for all results

Comment: I can't properly understand the question, but wouldn't the use of an array be also good? I think the OP wants to put 1st date in $date1 and the second into $date2. So I think it would be better to use an array, and $dates[0] and [1]... But I'm not sure, if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: Use an array to store the result, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741425/populate-php-array-from-while-loop

Comment: I want that each row,the date will put into variable every time it will loop

Comment: in the same variable? why would you want that?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     $results[] = $row['TheDate1']
}
echo $results[0];
echo $results[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

While I have no idea why you want to have `$date1` and `$date2` instead of `$date` as an array of two elements, here's a way to do it:

```
$i = 1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    ${"date".$i} = $row['TheDate'];
    $i++;
}
echo $date1;
echo $date2;
```

A proper way would be to assign them into an array and access the data like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $date[] = $row['TheDate'];
}
echo $date[0];
echo $date[1];
```

To compare the two dates, you can do the followings:

```
$difference = $date2- $date1;
```

or in the array approach:

```
$difference = $date[1] - $date[0];
```

Comment: I want to put it in two variable so that I can computes how many days the person pays their bills

Comment: @BillHunter You can compute the days using the array as well. See updated answer.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array doesnt return an associative array by default

Comment: @Blacksonic Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), the default is `MYSQL_BOTH`.

Comment: this is also the answer but sorry sir I can only vote for 1.but I thank you also

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
$dates = array();
$allData = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ // switch to mysqli or PDO
    $dates[] = $row['TheDate']; // $dates will have all the dates
    $allData[] = $row; // $allData will have all the data in the query
}

print_r($dates);
```

**PS:**

Please consider switching your code to MySQLi or PDO - MySQL is deprecated since PHP 5.5, and no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create an array:

```
$dates = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $dates[] = $row['TheDate'];
}

var_dump($dates);

// Now if you *really* insist in having it in separate variables you could do:

list($date1, $date2) = $dates;
```

Also:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Each date is in their own row, so `$dates[] = $row['TheDate']` will suffice.

Comment: In foreign key there are two dates I want to view previous date and latest date.