# How to get data from database then make it into array so you can sort it?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, while-loop

So i've try out to figure out to sort the data I got from the database. I'm counting how many comments an article have, by counting the "article_id" in the comments table. This is my solution for doing that:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM articles");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row["id"];

$result_2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM comments WHERE article_id=$id");
$row_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_2);

echo $row_2['id']."<br>";
```

example output:
0
2
0

but I want to sort it like this:
2
0
0

So i've understand to use sort() for this, but when I use it it says the parameter must be array. I've tried everything to make the data an array like the solutions you see here:
[Populate PHP Array from While Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741425/populate-php-array-from-while-loop)

But it don't work. I know i'm doing something wrong. I'm a beginner.. So I hope I'm not an pain in the ass.

Thank you

Comment: You could add an `ORDER BY id DESC` clause in the SQL query.

Comment: why don't you sort it using mysql? this is what mysql is for. You can also get article with comments count using single SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *almost never* have a query inside the while loop of another query.

So, killing two birds with one stone:

```
SELECT `articles`.*, COUNT(`comments`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `articles`
LEFT JOIN `comments`
    ON `comments`.`article_id`=`articles`.`id`
GROUP BY `articles`.`id`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Done!

Comment: Thank you so much!, my mysql knowledge is very less. I must improve it that.. Is it possible to explain why never using a query inside another query?

Comment: Because it's not scaleable. Let's say you have a thousand articles. That's one thousand inner MySQL queries you have to run. If I did that for my site, where there are hundreds of thousands of Pokémon, the server would... explode!

Comment: Euhmm I have one question.. Is it possible to also showcase the articles output that don't have comments with 0? or atleast showcase them.

Comment: @user3328041 Whoops. Forgot that case. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use mysql for it? You can order it, and also get comments count by making one query:

```
SELECT articles.*, COUNT(comments.id) as comment_count
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id
GROUP BY articles.article_id
ORDER BY articles.article_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be achived through mysql using following query

```
SELECT COUNT(comments.id) as total_comments
FROM article
JOIN comments ON article.id = comments.article_id 
GROUP BY ARTICLE 
ORDER BY total_comments DESC;
```